# HOW TO IMPORT & EXPORT APEX_APPL_ACL_USERS FROM ONE APPLICATION TO OTHER?

Tags: import, export, roles, acl, apex

i am using apex application and i want to migrate my application from onw workspace to other.
All my tables ,functions, views etc are moved except application roles which are assigned to users(apex_appl_acl_users). anyone help me for this issue ..

Answer (score 0):

The users are not part of an application, they are part of the individual deployment. You wouldn't want your development users to be exported to production every time you deploy a new version. The solution is to manually export and import the users. There is an excellent blog explaining how to do it here: https://seanstuber.com/2019/06/06/extracting-apex-access-control-users/